# Carrot2 Score, Label, Phrases and similarity?

Tags: carrot2

I don't quite understand the difference between a label and a phrase in Carrot2, and they don't seem to give a clear distinction i http://doc.carrot2.org/. I tried printing them both out, but they are apparently the same(using kmeansclustering). Can somebody clear this up for me?

I was also wondering about the score. After the clustering, my clusters don't have any scores attached to them, am I supposed to compute these myself?

Regarding the similarity, is it possible to use Carrot2 to determine how similar a query is to the clusters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact meaning of label, phrase and score varies across the algorithms. In general, a label can consist of one or more phrases. Some algorithms always produce one-phrase labels, others may output labels consisting of multiple phrases. For the k-means clustering, you can set the number of words per label using the [labelCount](http://doc.carrot2.org/#section.attribute.BisectingKMeansClusteringAlgorithm.labelCount) attribute.

Cluster score is also algorithm-specific and is the clustering algorithm's beliefs on the quality of the cluster. The current implementation of K-means indeed does not produce any score. If you'd like to compute one of the [common cluster quality metrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#Internal_evaluation), the easiest way would probably be to directly extend the code of the algorithm as it would give you access to the [vector space model](https://github.com/carrot2/carrot2/blob/master/core/carrot2-algorithm-kmeans/src/org/carrot2/clustering/kmeans/BisectingKMeansClusteringAlgorithm.java#L246) you'd need to calculate centroids and distances.

When it comes to computing the similarity between query and a cluster, there are again many possibilities. For k-means clusters you could for instance assume the vector space model and compute the distance between the vector corresponding to the query and the cluster's centroid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when you say directly extend the code of the algorithm, what do you mean exactly by that? Because I don't believe I am able make any class extend org.carrot2.clustering.kmeans. Am I wrong?